# How do I develop for the Unity Control Center?

Tags: programming, unity-control-center

I found no source on how to create an entry in Unity Control Center. Is it even possible? What languages can I use?

**Edit:** I'm searching for a method to have an entry appear in the Unity Control Center, and to write a component or whatever that lives INSIDE this window. Not a launcher only solution.

Comment: I edited the question. The other question searches for methods of creating a launcher entry, and the answers are focused on that process as well. While I don't find this question an exact duplicate, thanks for pointing me to that question. I never thought of calling the `Unity Control Center` `System Settings`, probably that's why I found nothing.

Comment: It is a duplicate, and it should say what you need to do?

Comment: I think that doing more than adding extra launchers would require source code tweaking.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Exactly what I was asking for. Or do you mean tweaking the control centre itself?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that's what I mean.